# Edit the email template content before sending to the user

Tags: email, html

I have created a custom(without using letterhead) email template with HTML content.I have made the contenteditable=true in the HTML version. But when I try to edit the email template and send the email to a user,these edits are removed and the email reverts back to the original. What can I do so that the changes made in the email template are there when I send the email to the user?